# Error when using a backslash in a Workflow Foundation InArgument<string>

Tags: c#, wcf, workflow-foundation-4

Our Workflow Foundation service uses a string parameter to pass XML into the service.

`public InArgument<string> XMLPayload {get; set;}`

We are using this `InArgument` to build a local variable inside of our CodeActivity:

```
public sealed class OurService: CodeActivity
{
    public InArgument<string> XMLPayload {get; set;}
    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
            var xmlPayload= XMLPayload.Get(context);

            //Rest of Our Code
    }
}
```

The problem occurs when we submit a an unescaped `\`.

**Works:**

`<test>this is \\ a test</test>`

**Doesn't Work:**

`<test>this is \ a test</test>`  returns `null` in `xmlPayload`

We are serializing our objects using `XmlSerializer` and have no problems setting them to strings before they are passed to Workflow.

We are passing the string through a `ServiceReference` to the WF service.

Our assumption is that the `InArgument<string>` initializer is unable to handle the literal payload.

**What we've tried:**

We have looked for ways to automatically escape `\` in `XMLSerializer` and ways to customize the `InArgument`, neither have been successful.

We are currently escaping the `\` but that's actually resulting in two literal backslashes in our `xmlPayload`

**The problem is not just an XML problem.** Any string passed to workflow that has a backslash will not make it through the `InArgument` conversion.

**Is there a simple solution we are missing?**

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce it with a simple CodeActivity and XMLSerializer. It's probably a WCF issue (which I doubt) or the way you're passing the string to the service. Try to update your question with a working sample.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. We are using WCF Test Client to connect to the XAMLX file and send the string. We can send just a regular string with a `\ `  in it and the InArgument initialization returns null to `xmlPayload`

Comment: So, WCF Test Client is your problem, not the code itself: [C# WCF: Backslash Limitation in WCF Test Client](http://www.programmersranch.com/2014/08/c-wcf-backslash-limitation-in-wcf-test.html)

Comment: That might be it. We'll test.

Comment: @Jota it appears you found our ghost error. I'll accept this as an answer if you submit it.